# How to read queue state in Jenkins which uses Azure AD authentication?

Tags: azure, jenkins, groovy

We had Jenkins instance with the Authorization mode `Logged in users can do anything` and single admin `superuser` with a token.

We used this groovy script to query for a build queue:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder {
  queueItems(Jenkins.instance.queue.items.collect { obj ->
      [
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.task.name,
        isStuck: obj.stuck,
        isBlocked: obj.blocked,
        isDisabled: obj.task.disabled,
        inQueueSince: obj.inQueueSince,
        why: obj.why,
        causesDescription: obj.causesDescription,
        queueItemUrl: obj.url,
        taskUrl: obj.task.url
      ]
   })
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

This worked well until we installed [Azure AD plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-ad).
When we did so, script execution request became to produce an error:

```
Date: Thu, 01 Aug 2019 15:03:29 GMT 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff 
X-You-Are-Authenticated-As: superuser 
X-You-Are-In-Group-Disabled: JENKINS-39402: use -Dhudson.security.AccessDeniedException2.REPORT_GROUP_HEADERS=true or use /whoAmI to diagnose 
X-Required-Permission: hudson.model.Hudson.RunScripts 
X-Permission-Implied-By: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer 
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT 
Cache-Control: no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate 
X-Hudson-Theme: default 
Referrer-Policy: same-origin 
X-Hudson: 1.395 
X-Jenkins: 2.186 
X-Jenkins-Session: 9cf3a1af 
X-Hudson-CLI-Port: 50000 
X-Jenkins-CLI-Port: 50000 
X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port: 50000 
X-Frame-Options: sameorigin 
Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT) 
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

We tried to use domain user to authenticate this request like so:

```
curl -k -X POST -u "USERNAME@DOMAIN:PASSWORD"  -d "script=%0A%20%20%20%20def%20builder%20%3D%20new%20groovy.json.JsonBuilder()%0A%0A%09builder%20{%0A%09%20%20queueItems(Jenkins.instance.queue.items.collect%20{%20obj%20-%3E%0A%09%09%20%20%5B%0A%09%09%09id%3A%20obj.id%2C%0A%09%09%09name%3A%20obj.task.name%2C%0A%09%09%09isStuck%3A%20obj.stuck%2C%0A%09%09%09isBlocked%3A%20obj.blocked%2C%0A%09%09%09isDisabled%3A%20obj.task.disabled%2C%0A%09%09%09inQueueSince%3A%20obj.inQueueSince%2C%0A%09%09%09why%3A%20obj.why%2C%0A%09%09%09causesDescription%3A%20obj.causesDescription%2C%0A%09%09%09queueItemUrl%3A%20obj.url%2C%0A%09%09%09taskUrl%3A%20obj.task.url%0A%09%09%20%20%5D%0A%09%20%20%20})%0A%09}%0A%0A%09println%20builder.toPrettyString()" https://jenkinsurl/scriptText
```

It works well the using from the RESTer Chrome plugin, but we did't manage to make it work using another programs like CURL.

We identified the problem with a cookies, which cannot be set before the first request is sent.

So, what is the correct way to read jobs queue (using curl) in a such Jenkins configuration?

We need either using an existing Jenkins user token instead of AD auth for that action or use some plugin which will read the queue and return this data without any authentication.

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54115

Answer (score 2):

There are currently only two workarounds that I could find for this. The issue has been raised on the Jenkins GitHub.

Jie Shen suggested the following on the [Jenkins issue page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54115) for helping ensure access:

> In the Azure Active Directory Matrix-based security section, you need
>   to have two users in the matrix to make it work for accessing Jenkins
>   API. The auto-completion will provide you a user name like 'username
>   (object id)'. Besides this, you need to add a user name like 'username
>   (user ID)' and give it the reading permission. By that, the API things
>   should work.

Also, confirm that your curl request matches the output of your RESTer Chrome plugin request. Most likely your curl command does not generate the same output as the RESTer Chrome plugin.